# Can AWS CodeDeploy be used to deploy a single application to both Linux and Windows servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

The AWS CodeDeploy `appspec.yaml` format defines an `os` parameter, which the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure.html)  defines as:

> This section specifies the operating system value of the instance to
>   which you deploy. It is required. The following values can be
>   specified:
>
> linux – The instance is an Amazon Linux, Ubuntu Server, or RHEL
>   instance.
>
> windows – The instance is a Windows Server instance.

Does this mean that CodeDeploy does not support deploying the same application to both Windows and Linux servers using the same application definition?  For example, I may have a java application that will run quite happily on both servers - is this supported?

Comment: I have the same problem